# Commit details not show after upgrade gitlab from 6-7-stable to any other version

Tags: ruby, upgrade, gitlab

I have Gitlab Community Edition 6-7-stable with. When I upgrade it to any other version, I cannot see commit details at all -- error 500. As I can see, all gitlab work perfectly after upgrade, except "little" trouble above.

production.log;

```
Started GET "/myproject-ru/myproject_ru_rating/commit/b01d59be5ac7345c2eef984018b9cf6a1c3697e0" for 94.190.193.26 at 2014-12-15 07:36:06 -0500
Processing by Projects::CommitController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"myproject-ru/myproject_ru_rating", "id"=>"b01d59be5ac7345c2eef984018b9cf6a1c3697e0"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 190ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `system=' for #<Note:0xacc4548>):
  app/models/project.rb:269:in `build_commit_note'
  app/controllers/projects/commit_controller.rb:25:in `show'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:59:in `set_current_user_for_thread'
```

root@gitlab:/home/git/gitlab# sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

```
System information
System:     Debian 7.7
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   1.9.3p545
Gem Version:    1.8.23.2
Bundler Version:1.7.9
Rake Version:   10.3.1
Sidekiq Version:2.17.0

GitLab information
Version:    6.9.2
Revision:   e46b644
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        http://my.git.host
HTTP Clone URL: http://my.git.host/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@my.git.host:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.9.4
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

Command

`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`

show all items green.

- I tried upgrade to latest version -- problem persists.
- I tried rebuild all bundles and recompile assets -- problem persists.
- I tried upgrade ruby to latest version -- problem persists.
- I tried set up fresh Gitlab 6-7-stable, migrate my data to it and then upgrade this installation -- problem persists.

Any ideas will be great.